# How to edit a .bat file with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, batch-file, edit, excel-addins

I'm developing an Excel Add-in for .bat / .vbs files.  The add-in has 2 options (1) create a new .bat / and .vbs file and (2) modify an existing .bat and .vbs file.

The "create" option is working great and does exactly what we need it to do.

I'm having issues with the "modify" piece.  When the user selects "modify", and Excel form is displayed with a List Box.  The user scrolls through the list and selects the one they need to modify.  So far so go.

The next step is for the add-in to open (not run) both the .bat and .vbs file.  I've been able to get the .bat file to execute; which in turns executes the .vbs file.  But that is not what I need it to do.

If I was going to manually open the .bat or .vbs file.  I would right click on the .bat or .vbs file and select "edit".  The appropriate file opens in NotePad.  I can then make any changes and save the file.

What I'm looking duplicate is the "right click and select edit steps" with VBA.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreicated.  Thanks for your help in advance....

Comment: You could use the registry, example: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\.bat` and use its `Default` value usually `batfile`, to access its key e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\batfile`, then verify that its default value is still `Windows Batch File`, and if so, get  the content from the `Default` value of its sub-key, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\classes\batfile\Shell\Edit\Command`, which on an untouched system would be, `"%SystemRoot%\System32\Notepad.exe" %1`. You may also need to check the same for the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` version of the same key too, then do it again with `.vbs`

Comment: I would advise however that you do not cut corners, and just assume that the end user has never modified, their system or user registry. There is nothing stopping them from using a different application for handling files as they require, and you should therefore not expect otherwise.

Comment: Instead of execute the .bat file, you need to execute this line: `notepad filename.bat`. This may also serve to create a new .bat file, when it does not exists.

Comment: That @Aacini, however is assuming that no changes have ever been made, which is not technically what was asked. The job is to replicate the right-click `Edit` option, and the only way to do that is to retrieve the command run when `Edit` is selected. Many people, do not want the ancient and featureless notepad.exe to handle their script editing.

Comment: Both .bat and .vbs files are simply text files so use whatever mechanism you like to edit a text file. Open in notepad? Open in a special VBA form that has a text control? BTW... this sounds far more complicated than simply maintaining these files directly in explorer / notepad

Comment: @Shaves, does any answer fits your question?

Comment: @NandanA...........I apologize for the delay.  I got pulled into another project this week and haven't gotten back to this.  I'll be looking at it next week (hopefully).

I don't think I want to get into renaming the files over and over again.  While it should work.  I'm not going to pursue that option.

Nick.McDermaid said it is more complicated than maintaining them in explorer.  I agree.  We often create things like this to enhance our skill set and then share it with other developers on our team.  We have done this for years and have used things like this on other projects.

Comment: @NandanA.............I used the answer from Gokhan Aycan below.  It got me closest to what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Add-Ins, sorry if misleading. This does work in normal code:

Assume there is a userform frmTest7 with TextBox1, ListBox1 and CommandButton1 (to save changes). The userform code as follows.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim oFile As TextStream
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    FilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\desktop\test_bat.bat"
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To frmTest7.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        strFile = strFile & frmTest7.ListBox1.List(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    
    If fso.FileExists(FilePath) Then
        'fso.DeleteFile (FilePath)
        Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath, True)
        oFile.WriteLine strFile
    End If
    
    If Not (oFile Is Nothing) Then oFile.Close
    
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    frmTest7.TextBox1.Text = frmTest7.ListBox1.List(frmTest7.ListBox1.ListIndex)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()

    frmTest7.ListBox1.List(frmTest7.ListBox1.ListIndex) = frmTest7.TextBox1.Text

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim oFile As TextStream
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    FilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\desktop\test_bat.bat"
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePath, ForReading)
    
    strFile = oFile.ReadAll
    
    oFile.Close
    
    Dim arrStrFile() As String
    
    strFile = Replace(strFile, vbCr, "")
    arrStrFile = Split(strFile, Chr(10))
    
    frmTest7.ListBox1.Clear
    frmTest7.ListBox1.List = arrStrFile
    
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: ................I was able to your answer to do what I needed done.  I modified it slightly because I have 2 files I need to open and view.  I put the text boxes side by side and it works like I expected it to.  Thanks for the help.......

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this but not sure whether it works for you or not.

**1**. We cannot open `.bat` files but we can open `.txt` files so I converted the `.bat` file to `.txt` file and opening it using hyperlink.

In below example, Reminder is a `.bat` file and on clicking the Open button it converts the `Reminder.bat` to `Reminder.txt` and opens the file.

[image]

```
Sub RenameFileExtensionFromBatToTextAndOpen()
 
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileLocation As String
Dim originalExtension As String
Dim renamedExtenstion As String

fileLocation = "C:\Users\Nandan\Downloads\"
fileName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
originalExtension = fileLocation & fileName & ".bat"
renamedExtenstion = fileLocation & fileName & ".txt"
    
Name originalExtension As renamedExtenstion
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=renamedExtenstion

End Sub
```

**2**. After changes saved, on clicking Done it will change the file format from `Reminder.txt` to `Reminder.bat`

```
Sub RenameFileExtensionFromTxtToBat()
 
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileLocation As String
Dim originalExtension As String
Dim renamedExtenstion As String

fileLocation = "C:\Users\Nandan\Downloads\"
fileName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
originalExtension = fileLocation & fileName & ".bat"
renamedExtenstion = fileLocation & fileName & ".txt"

Name renamedExtenstion As originalExtension

End Sub
```

**On opening file,**

[image]

**After clicking on Done,**

[image]

Comment: Although this is a detailed answer, it is not necessary (or ideal) to rename a .bat file to open it in a text editor.